# How can I deal with an array of structs?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have this struct:

```
#define sbuffer 128
#define xbuffer 1024

typedef struct{
    char name[sbuffer];
    char att[sbuffer];
    char type[sbuffer];
    int noOfVal;
    int ints[xbuffer];
    double doubles[xbuffer];
    char *strings[xbuffer];
} variable;
```

I need to create an array from this struct, I did this

```
variable *vars[512]; //is it right
```

If I want to put a string that I had in s into the name, I did this:

```
char *s = "What Ever";
strcpy(vars[0]->name,s);
```

but this doesn't work for me, can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the `*` in this line:

```
variable *vars[512]; //is it right
```

And use **dot syntax** to access the struct member in `strcpy`:

```
char *s = "What Ever";
strcpy(vars[0].name,s);
```

Comment: i take it out but i now get an error in the strcpy function,,

Answer (score 1):

You've allocated an array of *pointers* to your struct, but never created instances (allocated memory) of them.  You could either make it an array of the structures (without the pointers) so you don't have to worry about memory management.

```
char *s = "What Ever";
variable vars[512]; /* an array of your structure */
strcpy(vars[0].name,s); /* <- use dot operator here since they are no longer pointers */
```

Or at least allocate memory for the structure before using it (and initializing all other pointers to `NULL`).

```
char *s = "What Ever";
variable *vars[512]; /* an array of pointers to your structure */
vars[0] = (variable *)malloc(sizeof(variable)); /* dynamically allocate the memory */
strcpy(vars[0]->name,s); /* <- used arrow operator since they are pointers */
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use

```
variable vars[512];
```

instead of

```
variable *vars[512]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
variable *vars[512] = {NULL};

int i = 0;

//i may get a value in some way

if (NULL == vars[i]){
    vars[i] = (variable *)malloc(sizeof(struct variable));
}
```